# How to use customized x and y labels with geom_tile() and facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have a dataframe:

```
   ddf <- structure(list(winner1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), loser1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), winner2 = c("A1", "A2", 
"A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", 
"A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", 
"B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "C1", "C2", "C3", 
"C4", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C1", "C2", 
"C3", "C4", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D1", 
"D2", "D3", "D4", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4"), loser2 = c("A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A4", 
"A4", "A4", "A4", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", 
"B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B4", "B4", "B4", "B4", "C1", "C1", "C1", 
"C1", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C4", "C4", 
"C4", "C4", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", 
"D3", "D3", "D3", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4"), value = c(0, 0, 1, 
0, 40, 0, 1, 2, 67, 4, 0, 0, 54, 11, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 56, 0, 
4, 0, 40, 16, 0, 0, 26, 21, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 47, 0, 0, 0, 30, 
11, 0, 0, 11, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 30, 0, 0, 0, 8, 12, 0, 0, 
6, 3, 1, 0), value1 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 40, NA, 1, 2, 67, 4, NA, 
NA, 54, 11, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 56, NA, 4, NA, 40, 16, NA, 
NA, 26, 21, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47, NA, NA, NA, 30, 11, NA, 
NA, 11, 2, 2, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 30, NA, NA, NA, 8, 12, NA, NA, 
6, 3, 1, NA), id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -64L), class = "data.frame")


head(ddf)

   winner1 loser1 winner2 loser2 value value1 id
1:       1      1      A1     A1     0     NA  A
2:       2      1      A2     A1     0     NA  A
3:       3      1      A3     A1     1      1  A
4:       4      1      A4     A1     0     NA  A
5:       1      2      A1     A2    40     40  A
6:       2      2      A2     A2     0     NA  A
```

I want to use `facet_wrap()` to create a row of 4x4 matrices using `geom_tile()` which I can do as follows:

```
ggplot(ddf, aes(loser1, winner1, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="black", size=0.5, stat="identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse") +
  geom_text(data=ddf, aes(loser1, winner1, label=value1), color="black", size=rel(2.5))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'red1', space = "Lab", na.value = "white", guide = "colourbar") +
  facet_wrap(~id, nrow=1)
```

which gives me the following output:

[image]

What I would like to also add are customized labels along the x- and y-axis.  So for the 4x4 matrix under "A" the x-axis would read A1,A2,A3,A4,  whereas the y-axis would read (going upwards)  A4,A3,A2,A1.  The matrix under B would have labels along the ticks of B1,B2,B3,B4 etc.  I have these values in the `winner2` and `loser2` columns.

I've tried adding `labels=winner2` into e.g. `scale_y_continuous()`, but that doesn't work as it not an object.

Although in this example the labels are quite straightforward being A1,A2,A3,A4 etc.  in other examples, the labels may not be in sequence like this e.g. for one plot they could be X4, W2, E3, C1.  Therefore I'd like to be able to label based on the value in the `winner2` or `loser2` columns.

Any ideas appreciated.

Also - I realize I could do this by making separate plots - but I would like to use facetting as this is part of a much larger plot.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `winner2` and `loser2`, use them in `aes`. You can set free scales in `facet_wrap` to make sure you only show the correct range in each panel.

```
ggplot(ddf, aes(loser2, winner2, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="black", size=0.5, stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(data=ddf, aes(label=value1), color="black", size=rel(2.5))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'red1', space = "Lab", na.value = "white", guide = "colourbar") +
  facet_wrap(~id, nrow = 1, scales = 'free')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. This is the same comments as the other answer. This does add appropriate labels, but doesn't allow the y-axis labels to go in the reverse, i.e. they should go A4,A3,A2,A1 as you go from bottom to top.  Is there any way of reversing the y-axes with this labeling?

Comment: It's easiest to change the factor levels. For example, you can change the aesthetics to `aes(loser2, forcats::fct_rev(winner2), fill = value)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by removing `scale_y_continuous()`, mapping `winner2` and `loser2` to the aesthetics, and setting `scales = "free"` in `facet_wrap:

```
ggplot(ddf, aes(loser2, winner2, fill = value, label=value1)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="black", size=0.5, stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(color="black", size=rel(2.5))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'red1', space = "Lab", na.value = "white", guide = "colourbar") +
  facet_wrap(~id, nrow=1, scales = "free")
```

Comment: thanks. This does add appropriate labels, but doesn't allow the y-axis labels to go in the reverse, i.e. they should go A4,A3,A2,A1 as you go from bottom to top.  Is there any way of reversing the y-axes with this labeling?

Comment: Try `+ scale_y_reverse()`

Comment: I should have mentioned that.  When you add that in to your solution, this is the error that comes up:  `Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator`  I believe that you cannot have free scaled axes in facet wrap and apply a reversed y-axis with different labels. That was my initial issue.